# Extraer cadena PHP

Tags: php

Tengo esta cadena

```
$cadena="Carla-Fernandez";
```

Y tengo que extraer el apellido, es decir, que me extraiga siempre lo que haya después del guión, de tal manera que aunque escriba un nombre con otra longitud me lo extraiga bien.

Comment: Utiliza explode otra separar cadenas por un carácter

Comment: ¿Que debería pasar si hay mas de un guión?

Comment: @Marcos Si lo que dice es claro.. debería extraer siempre lo que haya después de un guión.

Comment: @Excorpion disculpa, para mi no esta claro que si o si, es TODO lo que va después del PRIMER guion.

Comment: ¿De dónde salen estos datos? ¿De qué modo diferencias nombre y apellido en el origen? Como ya señala @Marcos en su comentario, si no garantizas que el guión es un carácter único podrías tener problemas en tu código. Por ejemplo, puede haber nombres o apellidos que lleven guión.

Comment: ya esta resuelto, gracias igualmente

Comment: @Alex ten en cuenta los comentarios que hacemos, porque tu pregunta no es clara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para separar una cadena se utiliza `explode` en el cual se indica como parámetros el carácter separador y la cadena a separar

```
$cadena="Carla-Fernandez";
$subcadena = explode("-",$cadena)
$apellido = $subcadena[1]
```

Y eto devolverá el segundo string que vendría a ser el apellido. Para saber más puedes leer la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

Comment: favor edita 'ecplode'  en tu comentario.

Comment: @Nor Gracias...

Comment: gracias, resuelto